# Is there a way to fix audio using Pygame on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I've been having this issue where I start my .wav file using pygame, it starts with a really bad quality and it seems like the sound has slowed down as well. I'm running my program on a Raspberry Pi 2 running Jesse, and I'm starting my program from my mac, not with the startx command. I've already been messing around with the frequencies with the pygame.mixer.pre_init(), and pygame.mixer.init()commands. 
Here it's my current piece of code that loads the sounds:

```
pygame.mixer.pre_init(96000,-16,1,4096)
happySound = pygame.mixer.Sound('happy.wav')
sadSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('speech3.wav')
```

and Here it's an instance where I call to play one of the functions:

```
if i ==0:
 print"1"
 print "N-H"
 ser.write('5')
 happySound.play()
i += 1
```

One more thing to mention is that I've connected an Arduino board to my Pi, and also I've a touchscreen attached to my Pi as well, so I don't know if this too much for my Pi to handle, or just another issue running Pygame on the Pi.
Any help clearing or solving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

According to this other [SE Raspi post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22076/playing-wav-files-with-pygame-bad-quality-with-noise), they recommend using the following settings for successful init of the Pygame mixer. (I dont think the Raspberry Pi's default output could support such a high sampling rate as 96000).

```
pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16, 1, 1024)
```

Another possible error is the ALSA volume is currently to low (so you will get distortion when the signal to noise ratio is too high). To set the ALSA PCM output level higher, try:

```
amixer set PCM -- 1000
```

About the slow playback speed; you will need to check what the sampling frequency of your .wav files are with a tool like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) or even use Python's built in [wave module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) (Wave_read.getframerate()). Then you will want to set your pygame.mixer.init samplerate to the wave file's samplerate.

Let me know if this helps!